# HOw to make the div to use the entire height in the grid?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

[image]

As given in the image , I want to make the left top image to use the entire height just like its neighbouring div in the first row of the grid. **How can I achieve it ?**

I result I want it similar to below

[image]

I am using `vue-js`and `Bootstrap` classes to style. No inline styling is used, so I only shared the `template` code . Although you are free to use it in the `<style>` section.  You can see the code below ( see the code for the row1 only , ignore the row2 code )

```
          <div class="container justify-content-center">
            <heading
              :heading-text="title"
              :view-all="viewAllText"
              :view-all-link="viewAllLink"
            />
            <!-- row1 -->
            <div class="row row-cols-2 justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div
                v-for="(banner, index) in gridCollection.slice(2, 4)"
                :key="index"
                class=" p-1 px-2"
                :class="`col-${4*(index+1)}`"
              >
                <fdk-link :link="`/collection/${banner.name}`">
                  <img
                    class="img-fluid object-fit-contain rounded-3"
                    :src="banner.image.landscape"
                    alt="Image"
                  />
                </fdk-link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- row2 -->
            <div class="row row-cols-3 justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div
                v-for="(banner, index) in gridCollection.slice(3, 6)"
                :key="index"
                class="col p-1 px-2"
              >
                <fdk-link :link="`/collection/${banner.name}`">
                    <img
                    class="img-fluid object-fit-contain rounded-3"
                    :src="banner.image.landscape"
                    alt="Image"
                  />
                </fdk-link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to give the column div a set height and then set the child div to 100% of the height you gave the column using Bootstrap class h-100.

```css
    .column_div{
        height:50vh;
    }
```

Comment: With some manipulations, it worked . Thanks for giving my attention to this side.